# CGGradientCreateWithColors returns a null pointer

Tags: ios, cgcolorspace

The problem is described in the subj.;
Here's my code below:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(NULL, (CFArrayRef)colors, NULL);
```

It's **not working**. Actually, the last call returns `nil`;

Neither it works when I replace the first argument `NULL` with a `CGColorSpace` reference, e.g. Device RGB.

What's wrong, does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to access the `CGColor` cast from `UIColor`:

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor, nil];
```

Also, specifying a color space is recommended:

```
CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(space, (CFArrayRef)colors, NULL);
```

Comment: I didn't think you could just stick CGColorRefs (they aren't NSObjects?) into an NSArray like that? When I use [NSValue valueWithPointer:] I still get nil back for gradient. I'm missing something here...

Comment: WiseOldDuck is right, you can't just stick CGColors into an NSArray.  You have to typecast each one to (id) first.  Once you do that, THEN the above works.

Answer (score 3):

`CGGradientCreateWithColors()` expects an array of `CGColorRef`s, not `UIColor`s. AFAIK `UIColor` is not toll-free bridged with `CGColorRef`.

Answer (score 2):

```
CGFloat locations[2];
locations[0] = 0.0;
locations[1] = 1.0;

CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(space, (CFArrayRef)colors, locations);
```

Comment: If locations is NULL, the first color in colors is assigned to location 0, the last color incolors is assigned to location 1, and intervening colors are assigned locations that are at equal intervals in between.